# How to make sure a string has a certain format

Tags: java, string

currently I have a code like this

```
public class Department {

    public static final String MESSAGE_DEPARTMENT_CONSTRAINTS =
            "Department names should only contain alphanumeric characters and spaces, and it should not be blank\n"
            + "Department names should start with a name, followed by 'Management'";


    public static final String DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX = "[\\p{Alnum}][\\p{Alnum} ]*";

    public final String fullDepartment;

    public Department(String department) {
        requireNonNull(department);
        checkArgument(isValidDepartment(department), MESSAGE_DEPARTMENT_CONSTRAINTS);
        fullDepartment = department;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if a given string is a valid department name.
     */
    public static boolean isValidDepartment(String test) {
        return (test.matches(DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX) && (test.indexOf("Management") >= 0));
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fullDepartment;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other == this // short circuit if same object
                || (other instanceof Department // instanceof handles nulls
                && fullDepartment.equals(((Department) other).fullDepartment)); // state check
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return fullDepartment.hashCode();
    }

}
```

I would like the code to only allow only valid departments name to be created

Example:

- Junior Management
- Senior Management

However, now I'm facing a problem where the word Management can be placed at anywhere and it's still considered valid

Example:

- Management
- Management Junior

How can I ensure that the word Management is a requirement at the back of a department name when I'm creating a department? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this function to this:

```
public static boolean isValidDepartment(String test) {
  return test.matches(DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX) 
              && test.endsWith("Management") 
              && !test.equals("Management");
}
```

If you think you will need more sophisticated checks you can also change your department validation regex to:

```
public static final String DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX = "(\\p{Alnum}+ )+Management";

public static boolean isValidDepartment(String test) {
  return test.matches(DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX);
}
```

Note that this will still allow `"Management Management"` and also `"M8n8g3m3nt Management"` since you used `\\p{Alnum}`. If you only need alphabet characters 
use `\\p{Alpha}`. If you want to catch the exception of `"Management Management"` you might want to do:

```
public static boolean isValidDepartment(String test) {
  return test.matches(DEPARTMENT_VALIDATION_REGEX) 
              && !test.equals("Management Management");
}
```

You should be able to do it all through the regex, but might get too complicated and unreadable for just one exception you can easily check with `.equals()`.

Comment: Was going to suggest the same, you have however missed space in the department part, now "Foo Bar Management" is not allowed.

Comment: Yeah I had missed that since it wasn't in the examples the OP mentioned as valid.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do it

a. Using `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` in **[StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)** ,or just `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` that `String` provides

```
boolean endsWith = StringUtils.endsWith("Managemet") && !StringUtils.startsWith("Managemet");
```

b. Using regex `.*?Management$`,in this expression using `.*?` to include space and other special characters

```
String str ="Test Management";
String regex = ".*?Management$";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

Comment: Why use a separate Apache Commons library when `String` already offers `endsWith()`?

Comment: @jbx I use `StringUtils` is in case of the OP need to some other special operations